# Memory management during function call

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, parameter-passing

I was writing a code that involves handling a 2D array of dimensions [101]X[101] in C. However I am constrained in terms of memory being used at a given point of time.

```
void manipulate(int grid_recv[101][101])
{
     //Something
}

void main()
{
   int grid[101][101];
   manipulate(grid);
}
```

So lets say I create an array **grid[101][101]** in my *main()* and then pass it for manipulation to another function. Now does the function *manipulate()* copy the entire matrix **grid** into **grid_recv** i.e by this sort of passing am I using twice the amount of memory ( i.e twice the size of **grid**)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. In C, arrays cannot be passed as parameters to functions.

What you actually do is creating a pointer pointing the array. So the extra memory you use it only the size of that pointer created.

Comment: So basically what you mean is that even if I receive the array as grid_recv[101][101] (and not int ** grid_recv) ,  I am still receiving a pointer? Then how is the size of the array incorporated into the picture?

Comment: @Dubby Yes, I mean there's no possible way to pass the array itself as a parameter, in C. I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you need the array's size in the function then you need to pass it as an extra argument.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question :) 
And one last question : how do i decide when to use the int  ** arr representation and the int arr[n][n] representation to initialize an 2D array? Also does C allow variable size array initialization ?

Comment: @Dubby In you example you have a pointer to a 2D array. `int grid_recv[101][101]` == `int (*grid_recv)[101]`. `int** arr` is a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Comment: My bad! Thanks! @self.
But when do I use grid_recv[101][101] or (*grid_recv)[101] ? 
Is there any benefit of receiving an array via an explicit pointer array ((*grid_recv)[101]) over the standard array notation?

Comment: @Dubby In that case the only difference is notation.

Comment: @self. And does C99 permit variable sized initialization? Can I declare a variable `int size` whose value is inputted by the user and then do something like `int arr[size]` ?

Comment: @Dubby yes you can do like that (only in C99),But You can do that only once in your  program,you cannot change its size again by assigning different value to `int size` variable.